# Why are rational numbers required in cusps of congruence subgroups?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

While we consider the action of congruence subgroups on $\mathbb{H}$ (the upper half plane), we compactify using an additional point at infinity, that is fine. But why do we add even all rational numbers? I am talking about how cusps are defined. And in particular, if $f$ is modular form, what does $f(q)$ (where $q \in \mathbb{Q}$) mean?

Comment: You are making a group *act* on the upper half plane.  If you want to add infinity into the space then you sure better include the other points in its orbit under the group, and when ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ acts the orbit of $\infty$ aside from $\infty$ itself is in fact all the rational numbers.

Comment: @KCd If you would be willing to post that as an answer, then I would upvote and this would no longer be on the unanswered list.

Comment: @MarkS.  okay, done.

Answer (score 3):

(I am turning my old comment above into an answer.)

You are making a group *act* on the upper half plane. If you want to add infinity to the space, then you should also include the other points in its orbit under the group. When ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ acts, the orbit of $\infty$ is $\infty$ and all rational numbers, so we are obligated to throw in the rational numbers too.